# Standalone testing of proprietary device drivers: seeking advice on h/w setup

Tags: drivers, redhat-enterprise-linux, hardware-rec, integration, proprietary

I am part of a large scale project which uses proprietary cards. The project had acquired these cards back in 2015 and at the time of acquisition, the drivers supplied (including source code which we have access to) were built to work on RHEL6. Subsequently, the vendor took those cards off their shelves, and do not offer any upgrades for their drivers. Our project is now migrating to RHEL8, and as part of that, we would want to test the drivers in an isolated setup after porting, before integrating them with the production environment. This we feel is necessary to avoid any risk of the OS (RHEL8) crashing upon the device drivers booting.

So the question is, what is the simplest and most effective hardware setup that can be put in place to validate the device drivers in isolation? Our project has been using Compact PCI chasis to host the cards.

Any advice would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: The simplest solution?  Take the storage device out of one of the hosts, clone the drive, then upgrade to RHEL 8 using an ISO.  This way you can test on the actual hardware that will be running RHEL 8

Comment: @Ramhound the method suggested is not clear to me. Did you mean take the card out of one of the hosts, clone the driver and then upgrade to RHEL8 using ISO?

Comment: No; I am suggesting you clone the storage device, to another HDD, boot to the clone, and upgrade to RHEL 8.  You will know fairly quickly if RHEL 8 is going to present a problem for your configuration.